# Chrome extension download "An error has occurred" after publishing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I am working on a Chrome extension and have just published it to the Chrome Webstore after it passed the review process. Now the extension is on the Chrome Webstore, but when I try to download it, it keeps saying that "an error has occurred," and Chrome throws an error saying "Failed - No file." Below is the manifest.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "(Name)",
    "description": "(Description)",
    "version": "1.2.2",
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon_128.png" 
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab", 
        "webRequest"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": ["popup.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```